# Enable navigator.virtualKeyboard in CRA production build

Tags: create-react-app, navigator

I am unable to see the navigator.virtualKeyboard API present in create-react-app production build, but it is present in local development. What settings do I need to tweak to enable it in production build?

Answer (score 0):

Please head to:
https://w3c.github.io/virtual-keyboard/

I´m not a React User, but I think that´s not your problem here, but this:
maybe your dev/prod systems have different setup.

[image]